# What do you need to build to house animals and monsters?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

I noticed that the chickens, cows and mosnters are roaming around the whole area they are assigned. What kind of building is required to house them? The only hint I got so far was to make a barn, pet bowl and a pet bed which will house the monsters, but what about the rest?

Also: does it house even the Stone Golem? This boi is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monsters and animals will sleep on pet beds provided, whether you build them a room or not. The only things required to make an Animal House are:

> 1 Pet Bedding
>
> 1 Pet Bowl
>
> 1 Haystack

Yes, even the Stone Golem will use an animal house (or just a pet bed)

Comment: You can also add whetgrass that will help feeding some of the animals inside the fences.

Comment: Absolutely. Wheat grass will attract these animals and keep them nearby, even without a room, and if you enclose a patch of wheatgrass with a fence (with a door) and add a haystack, you've got an animal paddock.